# ETS2 No "Edit Profile" in my game

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

I recently downloaded a mod for ETS2 and from that I already read its supposed to have a button that has "Edit Profile" when I launch my game to enable the mod, but it doesn't.

Any ideas? My OS is Win8 and the version of the game is 1.1.1.

Answer (score -3):

Change your game resolution or update your game version